# How do I put a CASE statement in a SUBSTRING statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring, case, where-clause

The purpose of this that I'm trying to compare the usernames of two email addresses and see if they're the same. Really, all I want is for this to work.

When I run the query, all I get is: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Note: I changed the query. This better illustrates what I'm trying to do. 
Note2: I've made the changes so it works properly, but now if the parameter is '', then I get: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

```
declare @ReportParameter1 nvarchar(16)
set @ReportParameter1 = 'manmoon@test1.com'
declare @ReportParameter2 nvarchar(16)
set @ReportParameter2 = ''
select 'test'
where SUBSTRING (case @ReportParameter1 when '' then 'x@' else @ReportParameter1 end, 1, Charindex('@', case @ReportParameter1 when '' then 'x@' else @ReportParameter1 end) - 1) = 
SUBSTRING (case @ReportParameter2 when '' then 'x@' else @ReportParameter2 end, 1, Charindex('@', case @ReportParameter2 when '' then 'x@' else @ReportParameter2 end) - 1)
```

Here's the where clause I used to fix the problem. However, this will teach me to be more careful when copying and pasting.

```
WHERE (substring(@ReportParameter1, 1, case when (CHARINDEX('@', @ReportParameter1) - 1) < 1 then 1 else CHARINDEX('@', @ReportParameter1) - 1 end) = SUBSTRING(@ReportParameter2, 1, CHARINDEX('@', @ReportParameter2) - 1))
```

Comment: You're using the SUBSTRING function incorrectly in the WHERE clause.  You're using it as if you expect it to return true/false.  Don't you want to equate it to something (ex: SUBSTRING(.....) = 'abc')?

Comment: All code regarding substring is fine except last `AND ()` in the `WHERE` clause you should put some boolean condition near it

Comment: That was part one of my problem. What I have now, is the actual problem. I should posted that first. My apologizes. I've rated everyone up for their answers. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from not comparing the result of the `substring` to anything. A string is not a boolean expression.

#### Edit:

Now that you edited your question, that answer doesn't make any sense any more.

I tested your substring expressions with empty strings, and I don't get any error. If you on the other hand have strings that are not empty, but doesn't contain any `@` character, then you get the error that you describe.

To handle that you could do like this:

```
... where case
  when @ReportParameter1 = '' or charindex('@', @ReportParameter1) = 0 then 'x'
  else substring(@ReportParameter1, 1, charindex('@', @ReportParameter1) - 1)
end =
case
  when @ReportParameter2 = '' or charindex('@', @ReportParameter2) = 0 then 'x'
  else substring(@ReportParameter2, 1, charindex('@', @ReportParameter2) - 1)
end
```

Note however that two strings that are not email addresses would compare as equal, as `'x' = 'x'`, so you might want to use different fallback values in the expressions...

#### Edit 2:

Come to think of it, you don't need to check for empty strings if you check for the @ character, as an empty string can't contain a @ character:

```
... where case
  when charindex('@', @ReportParameter1) = 0 then 'x'
  else substring(@ReportParameter1, 1, charindex('@', @ReportParameter1) - 1)
end =
case
  when charindex('@', @ReportParameter2) = 0 then 'x'
  else substring(@ReportParameter2, 1, charindex('@', @ReportParameter2) - 1)
end
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. copy and paste is the work of the devil.

Comment: It seems like I came up with the same answer as you. Although yours is more robust. In any case, you get the check.

Comment: This is exactly what I was saying... however props to Guffa for flushing out the complete answer!

Answer (score 2):

put the substring in the case... you basically want a static value on one case... on the other ... use the substring on the "else"

```
 case GPS_Quotes.[Sales Engineer] 
        when 
            '' then 'some constant value' 
        else 
            substring(GPS_Quotes.[Sales Engineer], 1, ...{I don't understand what your are trying to do})
        end
```

Comment: The question was... "How do I put a CASE statement in a SUBSTRING statement?" ... there is the secondary issue that his where clause lacks a boolean expression.  My point was that he doesn't need to put the case in the substring...  I answered the question asked ... not the problem with the question.  hmm... maybe we are just splitting hairs.

Comment: No, that is the title, but to be fair, the title looks like a complete question although it shouldn't, and the question doesn't really contain a question...